# ErrorException Creating default object from empty value in Laravel 6

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

when I'm trying to update user I got this error

this error point out at `$user->first_name = $request->input('first_name');`

update method

```
 public function update($id, Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'first_name'         => 'string|max:255',
        'last_name'         => 'string|max:255',
        'email'          => "string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,$id",
        'password'          => "sometimes|nullable |string|min:8,$id",
        'avatar'           => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png,svg|max:2048',
    ));
        $password = bcrypt(request('password'));
    $user = User::where('email',$request['email'])->first();
    $user->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
    $user->last_name = $request->input('last_name');
    if(!empty($request->password))
    {
    $user->password = $password;
    }
    if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/images/avatars/' . $filename ) );
        $user->avatar = $filename;
    }
    $user->roles()->detach();
    if ($request['user']) {
        $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name','User')->first());
    }
    if ($request['editor']) {
        $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name','Editor')->first());
    }
    if ($request['admin']) {
        $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name','Admin')->first());
    }
    $user->save();


    return redirect('admin/users')->with('success', 'user is successfully saved');
}
```

Comment: Check your `$user` variable. It must be blank

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment `$user` is null because there is no record with the `email` you are providing.

Use `findOrFail($request['email'])` so that you throw a `ModelNotFoundException` in this scenario.

**OR**

```
$user = User::where('email',$request['email'])->first();

if(!is_null($user) { // check not null of $user here
    $user->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
    $user->last_name = $request->input('last_name');  
}
```

References:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/errorexception-in-profilecontrollerphp-line-98-creating-default-object-from-empty-value

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FindOrFail` method instead

so instead of using this line:

`$user = User::where('email',$request['email'])->first();`

use this:

`$user = User::findOrFail($id);`

so `FindOrFail` will get the user by `id` and if it does not exist it will fail and show 404 Not found.